# How to set the ICON image to each expnadle list group in android

Tags: android

I'm using a Expandable list adapter to put view which has 3 groups and each group has 4 sub children , currently each group has the same icon image .
I need to put 3 different images to the three groups .. How to put this in android ..
Pls help .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have extended the BaseExpandableListAdapter in your one class. In that you will have one method

```
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = convertView;
            MyHolder hldr = null;
            try{
                if(row==null){
                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.disp_lib_group_row, null);
                    hldr = new MyHolder();
                    hldr.txtv1 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtGrp);
                    hldr.imgv1 = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imgGrp);
                    row.setTag(hldr);
                }
                else{
                    hldr=(MyHolder)row.getTag();
                }
                hldr.txtv1.setText(getGroup(groupPosition).toString());


          EDIT    EDIT    EDIT    EDIT    EDIT
                   System.out.println("Group Position: "+groupPosition);
                   //    here you will get groupPosition, like 0/1/2/3
                   //    just check it by if condition and
                   //    set needed image in followin line code
                   if(groupPosition == 0)
                    hldr.imgv1.setImageResource(R.drawable.img0);
                   if(groupPosition == 1)
                    hldr.imgv1.setImageResource(R.drawable.img1);
                   ......  Check 2, 3 ......
          EDIT    OVER    OVER


                }
            }catch(Exception e){System.out.println("Error: \n");e.printStackTrace();}
            return row;
        }
```

Comment: Yes I'm using the ExpandableListAdapter in my class ,, from the above figure it changes the icon only when its expanded . In my application I need put three different figures to the three different groups when the group are shown in the view .. say for example I have Three groupname 1.Travel 2.price 3.extra , so three group name should have the three different image when I displayed on the view .

Comment: Hi, This code would help me a lot , I'm confused to create a xml file which holds the all the images .. Do I need to create a selctor which has the item for all the images and include this xml in the main.xml ..?